# how to scroll up the browser page in pycharm while executing code using webdriver selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pycharm

How to scroll up in the chrome browser page using PyCharm 3.9 interpreter while executing the selenium python code using web driver.

I have tried `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)")` but it is not working and showing error.

Comment: what error are you getting?